# How can I create a public directory for an app?

Tags: android, directory

I am creating an app which records voice and saves it on the 'external public folder' of its own name. The code I wrote works fine on android but doesn't work later on. It fails to create a folder. Can someone explain why?

I don't want to save in `com.application` folder.
I want Re-Recording directory to be created as external public directory.
Below is the code:

```
    folder= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Re-Recording");
    recordPath = String.valueOf(folder);

      private void makefolder(){
   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "processing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   if(permission()){
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "geting info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       boolean d=true;
       Log.d("tap", String.valueOf(folder));
       if(!folder.exists()){
           Log.d("tap","what?");
           d=folder.mkdirs();
       }
       if(d){
           
           Log.d("tap","created");

       }
       else{
           Log.d("tap","error");
          
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ask runtime permission to write external storage before creating folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose a directory where you can create your own.